# How to keep original image size when importing to Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

Whenever I import an image into a MS Word 2010 document, it randomly decides to change its size to whatever Word wants. I want my imported images to stay exactly the same size (in pixels), and if I want to resize them later, I can do it by myself.

How can I set Word to stop changing image sizes???

Thank you!

By the way, I discovered that if I resize the picture to 83% of the original size, it looks awesome (just like the original)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have experienced, Word will keep the original image size if it fits within the page borders. If the image is too large to fit inside the borders, Word will resize it.

If that is not what you experience, please provide a sample.

Comment: Not that experience for me. Whenever I import a picture to Word 2010, it gets resized almost randomly. It almost always ends up bigger than the original.

Comment: A sample file would help.

Comment: I haven't seen this sort of random resizing either.

Comment: You may want to check the dpi settings of the images. A 100 x 100 px image at 72 dpi will show larger than the same image with 150 dpi.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but I ran into this problem with bringing screenshots into Word 2016.

The problem is that Word wants to bring your 96 dpi image into a 220 dpi document. (Your dpi values may vary.)

When, say, a screenshot is pasted into Word, it inflates the size by a factor of 220 dpi/96 dpi ≈ 2.29167. (I don't understand the point of this "feature", but this is what my Word install does by default.)

To counteract this, after having pasted the image in, right click on the image and click 'Size and Position...". In the Scale subpanel, set your height and width percentages to 96/220 ≈ 43.6436%. This will scale the image back down to its original dpi.

**Bonus pro tip:** 
Wait until you've got all your (poorly sized) images pasted into your document; don't resize any of them until you're done writing the doc. When ready, resize the first image as described above and hit Okay. Then click the next image once and hit F4. F4 repeats the last process, so hitting F4 will now resize the next image to ~43.6%. Click the next image and repeat your way down the file.

**PS:** Incidentally, changes to *File>Options>Advanced>Image Size and Quality>Set default target output to...* do *not* affect how my install of Word resizes pasted-in images.